# Emulating scrolling of QScrollArea Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have following problem:
I have QScrollArea, inside of it QVBoxLayout with lots of QToolButtons in it. QToolButtons are created dynamically, through the work and they are added as follows:

```
QToolButton* btn = new QToolButton(ui.previewList);
btn->setCheckable(TRUE);
ui.buttonsLayout->removeItem(ui.buttonsSpacer);
ui.buttonsLayout->addWidget(btn);
ui.buttonsLayout->addItem(ui.buttonsSpacer);
```

Sometimes I need to scroll QScrollArea from my program to ensure visibility of some button or, when a button is added, of a last button, and there I get problems.

1. ui.previewList->ensureWidgetVisible(btn) won't do anything at all. Maybe it happens because btn is not child of previewList, but is child of VBoxLayout
2. When I try to scroll to the end, then all of the variants above will result in scrolling so just last button (which I need to be visible) is right out of the screen, though I checked with debug, I first add button and call update of main form and only then I enter function with scroll. Maybe I should do something to force QScrollArea to recalculate its contents and scrollbar limits?

   ```
   QVerticalScrollBar scrlbar = ui.previewList->verticalScrollBar();
   int max = scrlbar->maximum();
   //Variant 1
   scrlbar->setValue(max);
   scrlbar->triggerAction(QAbstractSlider::SliderMove);
   //Variant 2    
   scrlbar->setValue(max + ui.previewList->verticalScrollBar()->pageStep());
   scrlbar->triggerAction(QAbstractSlider::SliderMove);
   //Variant 3
   scrlbar->triggerAction(QAbstractSlider::SliderToMaximum);
   ```

So what is the correct way to deal with QScrollArea in such cases?

Comment: For you first point: You are absolutely correct!

Comment: @monamona great, but what can be done with it? I can't scroll layout, neither I can arrange buttons without one.

Comment: Your second problem sounds the layout did not update yet. Calling button->update() just queues a redraw.
You could try something like `QTimer::singleShot(0, scrlbar, [scrlbar](){ scrlbar->triggerAction(QAbstractSlider::SliderToMaximum); });` to make sure the event loop is executed before the scroll action.

Comment: @SteakOverflow nope, it still won't scroll all way down, even if I put some small value in singleShot, like 20msecs. But you put my thoughts in right direction, QApplication::processEvents() solve this problems. Thank you!

Comment: @CrazySage Could you like an answer if you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here are answers to this problem.

1. to make ensureItemVisible working I just needed to set layoutSizeConstraint to SetMinAndMaxSize (and yes, it is written in qt documentation, so I'm can say rtfm to myself).
2. For scrolling to maximum QApplication::processEvents() was required, thanks @SteakOverflow for idea about that.